# How to simplify css id name if its in a sequence?

Tags: html, css

**I am using a CSS code,**

```
#flip1, #flip2, #flip3, #flip4 {
  color: red;
}
```

**Is that anything like this to simplify the same,**

```
#flip1-4 {
  color: red;
}
```

*If yes, please guide me how to do it. Else, any other way exist like that also would be appreciated.*

Comment: no, why not add a common class to those elements? though, `[id^=flip]` may work, but you can't limit it to just 1,2,3 and 4

Comment: Id is unique and in this case you should go with class, you can add classname `flip` to all the elements and call it in css by using `.flip{ color: red;}`

Comment: I just shows that above CSS code as example. In my real case am using it for a script through id and also using 50+ id in same sequence of number in order at suffix. Just the whole CSS looks ugly and bunch. That's why wonder is that any wild card way excist to fulfill my need to make my code much better.

Comment: There is already another class used on those elements, So i can't combine the CSS of id with the class of same element will collapse my code. So, only using ID. Let me know if same possible with ID. I seen some wild card sequence to achieve the same but not understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selector` here to as if there is any element that has `flip` in it then add `color: red`

```
  [id*="flip"] {
    color: red;
  }
```

or

```
  [id^="flip"] { // which means id starts with flip. More specific version
    color: red;
  }
```

```css
[id*="flip"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="flip1">flip1</div>
<div id="flip2">flip2</div>
<div id="flip3">flip3</div>
<div id="flip4">flip4</div>
<div id="flip5">flip5</div>
<div id="flip6">flip6</div>
<div id="flip7">flip7</div>
<div id="flip8">flip8</div>
<div id="flip9">flip9</div>
```

Comment: better off using `^=` (so `backflip` wouldn't match) but still, you can't limit it to just 1,2,3,4 ... `flipping` would match etc

Comment: and totally ignore the side effect off having a different element with flip e.g, `<button id='flipbtn'>Submit</button>`

Comment: @JaromandaX Realised that and added that too...

Comment: That's exactly am looking for, Works fine as I need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could also utilize SASS and compile the `.scss` file where you could use a loop as long as it is just about writing less code:

SASS (.scss):

```scss
@for $i from 1 through 50 {
  #flip#{$i} {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

which will compile to this CSS:

```css
#flip1 {
  color: red;
}
#flip2 {
  color: red;
}
#flip3 {
  color: red;
}
#flip4 {
  color: red;
}

...

#flip50 {
  color: red;
}
```